# Batch file REG QUERY

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am writing a script a retrieve the value of the "DefaultUserName" registry key. I have:

```
@echo off
Title Kiosk Account Autologin Password Changer
::Search for current Kiosk Account . . .
echo Identifying Kiosk Account
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon /s
Pause
```

but I keep getting a syntax error. I am a beginner at coding and all help is appreciated.

The end goal is to have an input output table to automate the change of the "DefaultPassword" key depending on what the user name is. The company I work for is changing all of the passwords and I don't want to have to do it all by hand.

Comment: You need to protect the space in your registry subkey, using doublequotes, i.e. `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"`., which could be shortened to `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"` for reg.exe. You should also not use lazy code which searches for and assumes paths and extensions, instead of using `reg`, use `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe`.

Comment: I have changed that line to `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /k /t REG_SZ` with no success.

Comment: Why are you now using `/K /T REG_SZ`? Also as far as I know from my notes etc. there isn't always a value named `DefaultUserName`, under that key, so perhaps a specific user name has not yet been defined as trhe default user, and/or there is only one user account.

Comment: I thought I needed to be more specific to correct my syntax error, I was wrong. I changed the line to `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName` and it returns the desired information, but on to the next step. I want to use that query as the input for an if/then statement (i.e. if "DefaultUserName" is "A", then change "DefaultPassword" to "1"). The way these machines were imaged by the company, they all have both of those strings in the Winlogon key.

Comment: Try something like this oneliner: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^  *DefaultUserName  *REG_SZ  *A$" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultPassword" /T "REG_SZ" /D "1" /F 1>NUL`. This should add the required password setting only if the default user name was exactly the case insensitive string `A`. Please note that this will definitely need to be run with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Can you explain the different parts of the string? I want to learn as much as I can from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your additional requirements as stated in you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352755/batch-file-reg-query?noredirect=1#comment124368154_70352755), this should add the required password string value data, only if the existing default user name was exactly the case insensitive string `A`.

*Please note, because you are making modifications within the protected HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE root key, the examples below will need to be run with elevated privileges.*

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^  *DefaultUserName  *REG_SZ  *A$" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultPassword" /T "REG_SZ" /D "1" /F 1>NUL
```

The only thing which you may not understand here is the conditional operator `&&`. There are two conditional operators, `&&` and `||`, the former means if the previous command reported as successful, and the latter means if the previous command reported as unsuccessful. So what this does in the above case, is `findstr.exe` looks for a line which begins with one or more space characters, followed by the case insensitive string `DefaultUserName`, followed by one or more spaces, followed by the case insensitive string `REG_SZ` followed by one or more spaces, and ending with the case insensitive string `A`. To learn more about the `FindStr` command utility options, please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. If the returned string matches, it is printed via StdOut to the console window, so I have redirected that printing to the `NUL` device, because we do not need to see or use it, and the command following the `&&` is run. *(If it doesn't match the rest of the line will not be run)*.

For modifying the command line, *because let's be honest, you haven't really got a user name of `A`*, just change out `A` in the `FindStr` match, as needed. So for example if your were really looking for a default user name of `Michael` you'd use:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^  *DefaultUserName  *REG_SZ  *Michael$" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultPassword" /T "REG_SZ" /D "1" /F 1>NUL
```

Please however remember the output from your `findstr /?` command. You will note that some characters are special, so all user name strings may not work without escaping some special metacharacters.

Comment: That was very insightful. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: If I have an excel file "Book1.xlsx" with column "A" being "Username" and column "B" being "Password", could I have this script query that spreadsheet and use the corresponding Username and Password combinations? That would save me the hassle of needing to manually edit (possibly) hundreds of lines for each combination. The machine already knows the Username as it is using it currently, so I would need some logic to look for that Username in the spreadsheet and then update the new password. Is that possible?

Comment: An Excel file is a proprietary format, and is probably not what you should be trying to read from a batch file. However, the Excel file could be exported to a CSV, and that, as a plain text file could be parsed within a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Just put quotes in the actual command line:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /s
```

Without them, the space at `Windows NT` causes the syntax error, since then it treats `NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` as a passed (third) argument to `reg query` command.

Comment: `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName
` ended up being the winning solution